# Highlight objects with light in animation

Tags: animation, effects

I'm making an animation of a surgery and I want to highlight specific steps of the surgery in this animation. Is there a way in blender 2.8 to highlight objects with light so that other structures are more on the background?

Comment: you should show what kind of highlight you want, you could do it in the Video Editor, with a PNG that you put over your sequence

Comment: Highlighting specific objects can also be done by keyframing the emission value in that object's material.